# How to get a maximum or minimum result from a related entity?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, ef-core-2.0

I'm trying to get the First and Latest record from a related entity using Linq lambda expression, but, I'm getting a invalid typecast error. Would you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Here is the code

```
var all = DbContext.Players
                .Include(g => g.GameDetails)
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Name, x.IsActive})
                .Select(x => new {
                    x.Key.Id,
                    x.Key.Name,
                    x.Key.IsActive,
                    FirstGameDate =  x.Min( l => l.GameDetails.OrderByDescending( a => a.CreatedDate).First() ).CreatedDate ,
                    LastGameDate = x.Max( l => l.GameDetails.OrderBy( a => a.CreatedDate).Last() ).CreatedDate,
                    CreatedDate = x.Max( s => s.CreatedDate)
                } );
                .ToArray();
```

And the error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.InvalidCastException

"System.InvalidCastException"

'Unable to cast object of type 
'SelectEnumerableIterator`2[Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueBuffer,System.DateTime]' to type 'System.DateTime'.'
```

Comment: `FirstGameDate = x.GameDetails.OrderBy(a => a.CreatedDate).First().CreatedDate`

Comment: At a glance, two things pop out to me: First, what Rufus L said. Second, is grouping by the player's `Id`, `Name`, *and* `IsActive` properties really necessary? `Id` should be unique on its own. In fact, grouping shouldn't be necessary at all. Project an anonymous object with the player properties and the aggregations.

Comment: @RufusL now the error message is: `'IGrouping<<anonymous type: int Id, string Name, bool IsActive>, Player>' does not contain a definition for 'GameDetails' and no accessible extension method 'GameDetails' accepting a first argument of type 'IGrouping<<anonymous type: int Id, string Name, bool IsActive>, Player>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS1061)`

Comment: @madreflection I need to group by `Id` because I made a new Select after that. The select only get the right value, if the value is grouped. If I remove this, I get the following error message `<anonymous type: string Name, bool IsActive>' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no accessible extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type '<anonymous type: string Name, bool IsActive>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) `

Comment: @EduardoSantana As the two gentlemen @RufusL and @madreflection  above said  , do something like this 
`var all = DbContext.Players
                .Include(g => g.GameDetails)
                .Select(x => new {
                    x.Id,
                    x.Name,
                    x.IsActive,
                    FirstGameDate = x.GameDetails.OrderBy(a => a.CreatedDate).First().CreatedDate,
                    LastGameDate = x.GameDetails.OrderByDecending(a => a.CreatedDate).First().CreatedDate,
                    CreatedDate = x.CreatedDate
                } ).ToList();`

Comment: @madreflection You're right, I don't need the grouped data. I don't know why have I done this, maybe I have copied from another part of code.

Comment: @WamiqRehman I have removed the `groupby`, but now the following error is showed: `An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Sequence contains no elements'`

Comment: It's possible that you were translating from SQL. In that case, you probably had a join between `Players` and `GameDetails` but then you had to group by those three columns. Doing it this way will involve subqueries instead of a join. The subqueries will be joins in the engine but you don't have to express it in syntax; it won't double-hit the table to do the aggregation.

Comment: You should use `FirstOrDefault()?.CreateDate`. It was suggested the other way way because you were using `First` already, which we could only assume means you knew you had a row for each player. If you don't, you need to use `FirstOrDefault` and account for `null`.

Comment: @madreflection I was using First, because I have tried it from so many ways. But I think the correct is with FirstOrDefault, because the record in related entity, can or not exists. Anyway, I put the `?` and the compiler returned to me this: `An expression tree lambda may not contain a null propagating operator. (CS8072)`. So I have searched it, and got the following result:

`FirstGameDate  = x.GameDetails.OrderBy(a => a.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault().CreatedDate == null ? (DateTime?) null : x.GameDetails.OrderBy(a => a.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault().CreatedDate `

It is working now. Thanks